# Making button selectable inside an unselectable ListBox

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, button, listbox

trying to make a button selectable inside a ListBox that is unselectable as defined by it's style. Is there a way that I can make it that buttons within the ListBox are selectable?

```
<Style x:Key="UnselectableListBoxItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" Fill="#FFBADDE9" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor2" Fill="#FFBADDE9" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer this question. 
We never came up with a solution that I was fully happy with.
What happened in the end was essentially a hack where we place the button outside of the listbox and move the button up a few pixels until it was in the desired position.
Not the optimal solution, but it worked anyway.